# Changing value of a variable with MPI

Tags: c, mpi

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>
int a=1;
int *p=&a;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

int rank,size;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
//printf("Address val: %u \n",p);

*p=*p+1;


MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Finalize();

printf("Value of a : %d\n",*p);

return 0;
}
```

Here, I am trying to execute the program with 3 processes where each tries to increment the value of a by 1, so the value at the end of execution of all processes should be 4. Then why does the value printed as 2 only at the printf statement after MPI_Finalize(). And isnt it that the parallel execution stops at MPI_Finalize() and there should be only one process running after it. Then why do I get the print statement 3 times, one for each process, during execution?

Answer (score 4):

It is a common misunderstanding to think that `mpi_init` starts up the requested number of processes (or whatever mechanism is used to implement MPI) and that `mpi_finalize` stops them.  It's better to think of `mpi_init` starting the MPI system on top of a set of operating-system processes.  The MPI standard is silent on what MPI actually runs on top of and how the underlying mechanism(s) is/are started.  In practice a call to `mpiexec` (or `mpirun`) is likely to fire up a requested number of processes, all of which are alive when the program starts. It is also likely that the processes will continue to live after the call to `mpi_finalize` until the program finishes.

This means that prior to the call to `mpi_init`, and after the call to `mpi_finalize` it is likely that there is a number of o/s processes running, each of them executing the same program.  This explains why you get the `printf` statement executed once for each of your processes.

As to why the value of `a` is set to `2` rather than to `4`, well, essentially you are running `n` copies of the same program (where `n` is the number of processes) each of which adds `1` to its own version of `a`.  A variable in the memory of one process has no relationship to a variable of the same name in the memory of another process.  So each process sets `a` to `2`.

To get any data from one process to another the processes need to engage in *message-passing*.

EDIT, in response to OP's comment

Just as a variable in the memory of one process has no relationship to a variable of the same name in the memory of another process, a pointer (which is a kind of variable) has no relationship to a pointer of the same name in the memory of another process.  Do not be fooled, if the ''same'' pointer has the ''same'' address in multiple processes, those addresses are in different address spaces and are not the same, the pointers don't point to the same place.

An analogy: 1 High Street, Toytown is not the same address as 1 High Street, Legotown; there is a coincidence in names across address spaces.

To get any data (pointer or otherwise) from one process to another the processes need to engage in *message-passing*.  You seem to be clinging to a notion that MPI processes share memory in some way.  They don't, let go of that notion.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer on the no of processes created is fine, but then the answer regarding why the value is set to 2 only still doesnt satisfy me. Because, I tried printing the memory location stored in pointer p for each process(see the commented line). It shows the same value for all the processes. That means even if the three instances of this program are running for the 3 processes, they are all showing the same address of 'a' in the memory. How is this possible?

Comment: Because your process (all of them) use virtual addresses. They can be the same in all process, but they all point to different memory locations, thanks to the paging system of your OS.

Comment: The only way to share information (that is, the current value of your "a" variable) among several process is by message passing. That's the point of MPI.

Answer (score 0):

Since MPI is only giving you the option to communicate between separate processes, you have to do message passing. For your purpose there is something like MPI_Allreduce, which can sum data over the separate processes. Note that this adds the values, so in your case you want to sum the increment, and add the sum later to p:

```
int inc = 1;
MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, &inc, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
*p += inc;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation there is no communication between the spawned threads. Each process has his own `int a` variable which it increments and prints to the screen. Making the variable global doesn't make it shared between processes and all the pointer gimmicks show me that you don't know what you are doing. I would suggest learning a little more C and Operating Systems before you move on.

Anyway, you have to make the processes communicate. Here's how an example might look like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>

// this program will count the number of spawned processes in a *very* bad way
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int partial = 1;
   int sum;
   int my_id = 0;

   // let's just assume the process with id 0 is root
   int root_process = 0;

   // spawn processes, etc.
   MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

   // every process learns his id
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id);

   // all processes add their 'partial' to the 'sum'
   MPI_Reduce(&partial, &sum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, root_process, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 

   // de-init MPI
   MPI_Finalize();

   // the root process communicates the summation result
   if (my_id == root_process)
   {
      printf("Sum total : %d\n", sum);
   }

   return 0;
}
```